# Access Sql about pivot

Tags: sql, vba

I have four tables now.

1. StuInfo
2. ActInfo
3. ActAttendance
4. ActLateArriveAndEarlyLeave

[image]

For Type, 1 = late arrive, 2 = early leave

Is it possible to generate a query like this with one sql statement?

[image]

C3:E4 are the cells which store the total time a person invloved in an activity.

Or if it is not possible, I want to export the final result to an Excel file.
How can I do it in VBA?
Thanks very much. Please let me know if I didn't explain clearly enough.

Comment: sorry that i cant upload the photos directly.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is what you need unfortunately I cannot find a way to export one from Access as a flat query. It will only export it as a pivot table in excel. This query will get you the correct data. Then you have to create a pivot from it

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  StuInfo.StuName AS Name, 
  StuInfo.Stu_No, 
  DateDiff("h",IIf([AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave].[Type]=1,[AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave].[Time],[AcctInfo].[sTime]),IIf([AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave].[Type]=2,[AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave].[Time],[AcctInfo].[eTime])) AS AttendedFor, Format([AcctInfo].[sTime],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS OnDate
FROM ((StuInfo LEFT JOIN AcctAttendance ON StuInfo.Stu_No = AcctAttendance.Stu_No) LEFT JOIN AcctInfo ON AcctAttendance.[Act_S/N] = AcctInfo.[S/N]) LEFT JOIN AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave ON StuInfo.Stu_No = AcctLateAriveAndEarlyLeave.Stu_No;
```

Then you can create a pivot table that looks like this

[image]

Obviously if you want something other than explicit hours you have to change the query a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A crosstab query can work. However, I need a little bit more information for what the values under date fields calculate. In my example I assume they are Max(Type)

```
TRANSFORM Max(Type) AS MaxOfType  
SELECT StuInfo.SteName, StuInfo.Stu_No FROM StuInfo       
INNER JOIN ActLateArriveAndEarlyLeave ON StuInfo.Stu_No = ActLateArriveAndEarlyLeave.Stu_No      
GROUP BY StuInfo.Ste_No, StuInfo.SteName      
PIVOT Format(ActLateArriveAndEarlyLeave.TimeValue, 'short date');
```